# Linq update only working once

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a method on a data context that takes an object, calls attach to match it with its database entry, refresh and submit any of the changes i make to the object.  The update works fine the first time but when i try to update the same entry a second time it starts throwing an exception. Here is whats in my update method:

```
this.GetTable(data.GetType()).Attach(data, false);
this.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, data);
this.SubmitChanges();
```

Here is the stack trace from the exception:

```
System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.
at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.Attach(TEntity entity, Boolean asModified)
at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Data.Linq.ITable.Attach(Object entity, Boolean asModified)
```

Am I missing some sort of table refresh?

Comment: Good on the stacktrace, but what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: sorry... i forgot to paste that in.  I added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the entity the second time, are you attaching it to the same DataContext instance? If you are, that's why the exception is being thrown. You only need to attach an entity once during the lifetime of the DataContext.

Comment: I see now. Is there a way to check if it was already attached?

Comment: MBU: One way of checking is to call DataContext.Table.GetOriginalEntityState(). If it returns null, then the DataContext isn't tracking the entity. I don't think this will work if your DataContext instance has ObjectTrackingEnabled set to false, though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Confirm `data` is not from `this`

   I suspect the instance you are trying to attach (`data`) is from the same context you are attaching to (i.e. `this`). You don't need to attach if it is from the same instance (it will simply update when you `SubmitChanges()` thanks to change tracking. If your code above is part of a method, let's call it `AttachAndSave()`, you can't call it with data you retrieved from that context, or call it twice in a row with the same data as it will try and attach the same data twice.
2. If `data` is from a different DataContext, try using the `asModified` parameter:

   this.GetTable(data.GetType()).Attach(data, true);

   My suspicion if point 1. doesn't help is that SQL is determining that you want to insert a new instance rather than modify an existing one, and it's then throwing an exception because your instance has the same Primary Key as another existing instance (i.e. the one you are trying to update). However, this will require a timestamp tracking field, and is unlikely to be the cause. Point 1 above (attaching an instance belonging to the current context) is most likely your issue.

Comment: if i switch it to true it doesnt work at all and i get this exception instead:

    System.InvalidOperationException: An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy.
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.Attach(TEntity entity, Boolean asModified)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Data.Linq.ITable.Attach(Object entity, Boolean asModified)

Comment: Not sure why it works the first time and when i try to update the same entry again a second time it fails.